# Lower five-second comment flag to three seconds

Tags: feature-request, flags, comment-flags, rate-limiting

Many times an obsolete comment ("I have updated the answer") and a subsequent "Thank you" follow each other. Many other situations occur where multiple flags should be raised for related comments.

While rate-limiting flags is understandable, it would be nice if the delay was:

- suppressed for users with sufficient reputation (e.g., 5k+);
- reduced to 3 seconds; or
- a sliding window to accommodate short bursts (of three flag notices).

Comment: Or use other on the post and request a comment thread clean-up...

Comment: @rene: sure.. If you want to wait a month.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Ohh, them's fightin' words.

Comment: @rene: Frankly, we prefer that obsolete comments be flagged individually.  It's much easier to see the though process in those four obsolete comments you flagged individually than it is to comb through 24 comments trying to figure out which ones you thought were obsolete.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, I only use that option if all comments need to go. I'm not trying to make your job more difficult...

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes yes **yes** :-)

Comment: I run into this limit sometimes. I just got tired of opening a meta post for every damn limit that I encounter.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Proposed solution: Make the limit once per second and 50 per hour. That removes the problem for users entirely (because 1 second is really low enough) and limits abuse even further (down to `50` from `3600/5 == 720` per hour).

I do not understand at all why the rate limits have to be so tight. This is an ongoing problem with this site. Power users are constantly slapped in the face by some overly strict limit that does not serve any discernible purpose in its strictness.

Please revisit all the limits, disable all "timer resets" and institute a layered limiting policy (x per second, y per hour, z per day). That way users are no longer bothered and abuse prevention becomes even tighter than before.

Note, that layered limits work well because user activity is bursty and bot activity is continuous. Allow bursts, stop sustained operations.

Comment: I *believe* that the maximum number of comment flags usable in a day is 100.

Comment: "100 per hour" - it is already max 100 per hour because it is 100 a day :D

Comment: Yeah... I try to make a more general point here.

Comment: I thought about including the information that there already is a 100/day limit. But I think this would just detract from the more general point I'm making. I'm intentionally keeping the wrong "720" number, too, because it illustrates the point so well. All the commentary below this answer is just a distraction. I argue for high burst limits and low long-term limits.

Comment: I cannot agree more with this proposal. I never understood the need for a cooldown period after every action. Even something simple like upvoting 2 or 3 comments at the same time becomes a chore. This change needs to be implemented.

Comment: No. Don't limit our ability to moderate.

Comment: I don't totally agree, but I do agree about removing timer resets.